# Add dictionary or list to Sqlite3 - Gives error operation parameter must be str

Tags: sqlite, python-3.6

Ok I am new to sqlite and python in general so please be nice =)
I have a simple dictionary -

```
time = data[0]['timestamp']
price = data[0]['price']

myprice = {'Date':time,'price':price}
```

myprice looks like this (time is a timestamp) -

```
{'Date': 1553549093, 'price': 1.7686}
```

I now want to add the data to sqlite3 database...so I created this -

```
#Create database if not exist...

db_filename = 'mydb_test.db'
connection = sqlite3.connect(db_filename)

#Get a SQL cursor to be able to execute SQL commands...

cursor = connection.cursor()

#Create table

sql = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST
            (PID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            DATE TIMESTAMP,
            PRICE FLOAT)'''

#Now lets execute the above SQL

cursor.execute(sql)


#Insert data in sql

sql2 =  ("INSERT INTO GBPCAD VALUES (?,?)", [(myprice['Date'],myprice['price'])])

cursor.execute(sql2)
cursor.commit()
connection.close()
```

But when executing this code I get `ValueError: operation parameter must be str`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the arguments of the `insert` statement in `execute()`:

```
sql2 =  "INSERT INTO GBPCAD (DATE, PRICE) VALUES (?,?)"
cursor.execute(sql2, (myprice['Date'], myprice['price']))
```

Also include in the insert statement the names of the columns.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. Error message gone but no data is added to db. Have to check somehow where problem is.

Comment: The create statement in your code creates a table named `TEST` but the insert statement adds a row to a table `GBPCAD`. Why?

Comment: Forpas you are fast =) I solved it. It was my bad using gbpcad as table-name in example. What was the problem was -
connection.commit()
and not cursor.commit()
Everything works like a champion! And so are you! Many thanks!